# 2016 target server is missing in SSIS deployment

Tags: ssis

I am using Visual studio 2022 for creating SSIS packages. Now I want to deploy my ssis package to a sql server 2016 version. However I am not able to select it from the list. what can i do? can someone please help me?

[2016 version is not in the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKB9q.png)